# ReactJS - issue about react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a `<Routes>` component that is rendering only a `<Dashboard>` component. The same thing isn't happening when I try to fetch the `<BillingCycle>` component. The Billing Cycles content isn't appearing when I digit the url in the browser that might fetch the BillingCycle' page. There is continuing showing the Dashboard Content. What do I mistake? Thank you.

import '../common/template/dependencies'
import React from 'react'

here is the parent component that imports the Routes component.

```
import Routes from './Routes'

    export default (props) => (
      <div className='wrapper'>  
        <div className='content-wrapper'>
         <Routes />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
```

here is the Dashboard component that is successfully appearing in these urls: http://localhost:8080 and http://localhost:8080/#/

```
import React from 'react'

export default props  => (
  <div>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
)
```

here is the billingCycle component that isn't appearing when I digit its url:
http://localhost:8080/#/billingCycles

```
import React from 'react'

export default props => {

  return (
   <h1>Ciclo de pagamentos</h1>
  )
}
```

Here is the Routes component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from '../dashboard/Dashboard'
import BillingCycle from '../billingCycle/BillingCycle'

export default props => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>      

      <Route exact path='#/billingCycles' component={BillingCycle} />
      <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
      <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```

Comment: In order to do that you must do it with server side render or also called isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use hash in URL you should use [`HashRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md). And you shouldn't add hashes to routes:

```
<Route exact path='/billingCycles' component={BillingCycle} />
```

Comment: what is it? hashRouter? some dependency?  can you please explain to me how do I implement it

Comment: Description and examples are in official documentation https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: I did a test replacing /#/billingCycles for /billingCycles and it didn't work there appeared an error message: Cannot GET /billingCycles in this url http://localhost:8080/billingCycles

Comment: I made little example for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/j22067pw03?fontsize=14. You can change url to /#/billingCycles and route will change.